# Show date in bibliography when quoting from an online newspaper (APA)

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I would like like to quote from online newspaper articles. According to APA6, [this should be done by printing the full date](https://apastyle.apa.org/learn/faqs/cite-newspaper) (not just the year).

I found this thread: https://texwelt.de/fragen/18642/reihenfolge-biblatex-bei-author# (German). There is a solution in there which, looking at the screenshot in the post, should do exactly what I need:

[image]

However, if I compile the exact same source code here, it’s still showing just the year:

[image]

This is the corresponding source code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{SpiegelOnline.2013,
 author = {{Spiegel Online}},
 shortauthor = {jok},
 date = {2013-06-09},
 title = {Obama verteidigt Abhöraktion Prism},
 url = {http://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/gespraeche-mit-merkel-obama-verteidigt-in-berlin-abhoeraktion-prism-a-906638.html},
 urldate = {2016-07-08},
 journal = {Spiegel Online}

% ... Stripped the additional two entries ...

}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true,german=quotes]{csquotes} 
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,language=ngerman,apamaxprtauth=99]{biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\DeclareFieldFormat{apacase}{#1}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{SpiegelOnline.2013}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

I suppose this happens because I’m using newer packages. These are the versions I’m running here:

```
Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
Package: babel 2020/02/28 3.41 The Babel package
Package: csquotes 2019-12-06 v5.2j context-sensitive quotations (JAW)
Package: etoolbox 2019/09/21 v2.5h e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
Package: biblatex 2019/12/01 v3.14 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)
Package: pdftexcmds 2019/11/24 v0.31 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
Package: iftex 2019/11/07 v1.0c TeX engine tests
Package: ltxcmds 2019/12/15 v1.24 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
Package: kvoptions 2019/11/29 v3.13 Key value format for package options (HO)
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
```

What do I need to do to make it display the full date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** Following https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/116 the next version of `biblatex` will look for the slighlty more idiomatic `entrysubtype = {nonacademic},` instead of `keywords = {nonacademic},`.

---

New versions of `biblatex-apa` (i.e. v9.0 and above that implement 7th. edition APA style) look for the keyword `nonacademic` in an `@article` to decide whether or not to print a full date.

If you add `keywords = {nonacademic},` to your entry, you should see the date again.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true,german=quotes]{csquotes} 
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,apamaxprtauth=99]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{apacase}{#1}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{SpiegelOnline.2013,
  author      = {Johannes Korge},
  shortauthor = {jok},
  date        = {2013-06-09},
  title       = {Obama verteidigt Abhöraktion Prism},
  url         = {http://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/gespraeche-mit-merkel-obama-verteidigt-in-berlin-abhoeraktion-prism-a-906638.html},
  urldate     = {2016-07-08},
  journal     = {Spiegel Online},
  keywords    = {nonacademic},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{SpiegelOnline.2013}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

[image: Korge, J. (2013, 9. Juni). Obama verteidigt Abhöraktion Prism. Spiegel Online. Verfügbar 8. Juli 2016 unter http://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/gespraeche-mit-merkel-obama-verteidigt-in-berlin-abhoeraktion-prism-a-906638.html]

Comment: I find the solution with `keywords` a bit unidiomatic, so I opened https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/116.