# How to fix APA-style formatting of references in the bibliography according item type

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting, citing, apa-style

I am using Overleaf with Zotero integrated as a reference manager and the package BibLatex for which the style is set to "APA". Due to the synchronisation to Zotero, I am not able to edit references.bib (read only).

Both **journal** articles as well as **magazine** articles (e.g., Havard Business Review) are classified as the same entry type "article" in BibLatex. However, APA's requirements have slightly different formatting requirements for the journal articles compared to magazine articles. For example, for magazine article, the month should be added behind the year. All other journal articles are working fine and are correctly formatted, but I cannot make any adjustment to the formatting for magazine articles.

What is the best way to fix this problem? Are there other packages I should use? Why does Biblatex not make a distinction since it is an APA requirement. I feel like I am missing something...

Note: For other item types (e.g., reports), I have decided to create a separate bibfile to adjust some of the data fields manually. Unfortunately, I cannot do the same with magazine journals are also classified as "articles". Thus, an error occurs and the bibliography cannot be fully populated.

MWE and example of the BibTeX Entry for a magazine article and below a journal article

```
\documentclass[review,authoryear,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa, apamaxprtauth=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

%% now in references.bib 

@article{isenberg_how_2010,
    title = {How to Start an Entrepreneurial Revolution},
    volume = {88},
    issn = {00178012},
    url = {https://search.ebscoho...},
    abstract = {The article refers to...},
    pages = {40--50},
    number = {6},
    journaltitle = {Harvard Business Review},
    author = {Isenberg, Daniel J.},
    urldate = {2023-06-17},
    date = {2010-06},
    keywords = {Business planning, Business success},
}


@article{theodoraki_building_2022,
    title = {Building sustainable entrepreneurial ecosystems: A holistic approach},
    volume = {140},
    issn = {01482963},
    url = {https://linkinghub.elsevier...},
    shorttitle = {Building sustainable entrepreneurial ecosystems},
    abstract = {Growing interest in entrepreneurial ecosystems...},
    pages = {346--360},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Business Research},
    shortjournal = {Journal of Business Research},
    author = {Theodoraki, Christina and Dana, Léo-Paul and Caputo, Andrea},
    urldate = {2023-06-17},
    date = {2022-02},
    langid = {english},
}


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is how the incorrect output looks now:

[image]

By the way, this was my first MWE, feel free to provide feedback if it was not clear and how to improve.
Many many thanks for your help!

Comment: AFAIK [`biblatex-apa`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa) has the entrysubtype nonacademic for articles in newspapers or magazines. But maybe this is not enough? So can you please show a [minimal working example with bibliography](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/277964) and also tell us, how you export the bib file? Do you, i.e., already use better bibtex for zotero?

Comment: As @cabohah says, you need to mark the `@article` as `nonacademic`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/551658/35864.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I added an MWE above
@cabohah: as I use Overleaf, I understood that biblatex incl. biblatex-apa is already installed. I have set the style=apa in the command (see MWE). Is there anything else I would need to do here? Unfortunately, the data field "entrysubtype = nonacademic" still does not show up automatically. As mentioned, I cannot edit the bible manually. Similar to "keyword=nonacademic"; I can only add this  in Zotero as an additional tag, but the final format doesn't change either. I installed betterzotero, but does not help here?

Comment: @user299207 with a correct bib entry this should just work, but you need `isenberg_how_2010` to have the key `entrysubtype = {nonacademic}`.  The TeX solution is to just edit the bib file (otherwise you're in [garbage in, garbage out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) territory). With Zotero's Better Bibtex try https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/exporting/#add-your-own-biblatex-fields

Comment: https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/comment/431873/#Comment_431873 suggests that BetterBibTex for Zotero should be able to let you set an `entrysubtype`.